# How to remove the title from input field in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, textbox, ctp

For an application, I am using cakephp with mysql.

I echo the existing contents from the table as:

```
<?php
echo $form->create('Post',array('action'=>'edit'));

echo $form->input('title');
?>
```

in the .ctp file.

This displays the title value retrieved from the table as well as 'title' near the text box. I do not want the word 'title' to be displayed near the text box.

How will I achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo $form->input('title', array('label' => false));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $form->input('title', array('label' =>''));
```